# How can I get rid of the nginx welcome page on docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to serve an Angular App on a Docker Container and every time it serves me the Nginx welcome page and I don't know why.

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install 
CMD npm run start:complete-interceptor-example
```

this is a basic dockerfile, it's building, it runs successfully, I tried that `CMD npm run ...` command, that is the command that starts my app locally, on the logs it says

```
[interceptor-example] ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:80, open your browser on http://localhost:80/ **

[interceptor-example] : Compiled successfully.
```

but nothing is displayed.

The commands I've been using were:

`docker build -t demo_app ./` 
and
`docker run -d -it -p 80:80/the-key-they-gave-me`

and I also have a command that I have to run after the app is running:
`docker-compose -f collector/docker-compose.yaml up -d`

and I tried to use that in the dockerfile, but was not working.
I'm new to docker and this is a little bit confusing to me. How can I get rid of the nginx welcome page and display my actual app and after that start the collector ( do I have to start it locally? ) ? Thank you so much for your time.

This is my folder structure
[image]

and these are the scripts from package.json file :

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build opentelemetry-interceptor --prod",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example,cypress\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold,yellow.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\" \"cypress open\"",
    
    "cypress:run": "concurrently -k -s first -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example,cypress\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold,yellow.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\" \"cypress run\"",
    "start:backend-interceptor-example": "node ./projects/interceptor-example/src/backend-api.js",
    "start:complete-interceptor-example": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\"",  
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -t -p projects/opentelemetry-interceptor/tsconfig.lib.json --theme material -d ./docs -n \"OpenTelemetry Angular Interceptor\""
  },
```

Comment: The Node setup you show doesn't include anything related to Nginx.  You mention a Docker Compose setup, though; can you include a [mcve] with an extract from the `docker-compose.yml` file showing what's getting run there?  (Where is the Nginx instance and how are files supposed to get into it?)

Comment: the docker compose file is just for the collector of traces, that's external, the app should run without it. Besides that dockerfile you saw above I have nothing else related to the docker, that's why I'm confused too, I didn't set an nginx instance anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you get your Nginx config from. I can share my Dockerfile which works for the angular and node as build plus Nginx as runtime step.

Im using [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine as builder #nodejs 
COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm ci --loglevel verbose && mkdir /ng-app && mv ./node_modules ./ng-app
WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY . .
## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN npm run build-hram -- --prod

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.21-alpine
## Copy our default nginx config
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx --from=builder /ng-app/dist/FinMes /usr/share/nginx/html
# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And for the Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  access_log off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

With the Nginx config above you make sure every request that comes to container port of 8080 will be routed to the compiled sources of the angular application.